# DBSet does not contain a definition for Where

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

When trying to execute a .Where() on my database context from a model, I am hit with this error message:

```
System.Data.Entity<RPSManagementSystem.Model.StoreUser> does not contain a definition for Where...
```

This works when calling it from a controller. What gives?

From the model:

```
[NotMapped]
private List<StoreUser> _stores { get; set; }
[NotMapped]
public List<StoreUser> Stores
{
    get
    {
        if (this._stores == null || this._stores.Count <= 0)
        {
            using (RPSEntities db = new RPSEntities())
            {
                this._stores = db.StoreUsers.Where(su => su.Username == this.Username);
            }
        }

        return _stores;
    }
}
```

Just to make sure I'm not crazy, I pasted this into my controller - where it looks to be working. Screenshots below:

in the model:

[image]

in the controller:

[image]

Comment: Have you added `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: @Alberto *facepalm* you nailed it. Can you post this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Add `using System.Linq;` in your model class

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but I think the OP is encountering the issue inside the model, not the controller. OP states it works in the controller. :-)

Comment: I noticed that is necessary to add `using System.Linq;` in any class that use LINQ features.

Comment: This works for DbSet.ToList() as well

Comment: I had this issue too, but with having the entry using System.Linq. In my case the foreign key was not correct, means it was not a many to many key, but a one to many key. That results in on the 'one' side being just one element instead of a list, so the 'Select' command made no sense. After correcting to many to many the error was gone :-)